# How can I solve $\int \sqrt{x}^\sqrt{x}dx$

Tags: calculus

How can I solve
$$\int \sqrt{x}^\sqrt{x}dx$$

Comment: $\frac{2x^{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+1}}{\sqrt{x}+2} +C$

Comment: I highly doubt there will be an elementary solution for this.

Comment: My hunch would be to write
$$
\sqrt{x}^\sqrt{x} = \frac{\sqrt{x}^{1+\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
and change variables to $u = \sqrt{x}$ with $du = dx/(2\sqrt{x})$, may be simpler. You end up with something like $\int u^{u+1} du$...

Comment: @Mike Rellek's solution is correct.  Wolfram Alpha can compute the answer, apparently.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28x%29%5Esqrt%28x%29, yes, I was trying to use the definite integral calculator to see the answer, but it wasn't working. apperantly you should use the x^(n+1)/n+1 rule to solve this.

Comment: 5 favs 2 downvotes and 1 upvote...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oddly, if you follow gt6989b's suggestion, Wolfram finds the solution is not elementary.

Comment: Anyone try to differentiate Rellek's answer and get the correct result?  I end up with some term multiplied by $\ln x$ that I can't cancel out.

Comment: I doub't that Rellek's answer is correct (never trust CAS blindly)...

Comment: Here's Wolfram's attempt: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+2sqrt%28x%29%5E%28sqrt%28x%29%2B2%29%2F%28sqrt%28x%29%2B2%29

Comment: Obviously Wolfram is wrong. Plugging $x=1$ into the derivative of this supposed integral gives $8/9$, not $\sqrt{1}^{\sqrt{1}}=1$, as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can I solve* $\displaystyle\int\sqrt{x}^\sqrt{x}~dx$ ?

[You](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)). [Can't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). You may simplify it to $~2\displaystyle\int t^{t+1}~dt~$ by using a simple substitution, for instance, but that's about it.

Comment: why is it not solvable post that substitution?

Comment: @MonK: Because solvability is not dependent upon the form of the integrand. If it was (un)solvable before, it will still be (un)solvable after, and vice-versa.

Comment: @lucian, Thank you for the response